# What is the correct way to update a list of contact phone numbers in Android?

Tags: android, android-contacts

I want to create a method that updates a contact, including its name (structured) and a list of phone numbers.

There is no any problem with Structured Name part, But I'm not sure about the contact phone numbers list. It is represented as a list of Strings. Here is what I have for the moment:

```
val phonesSelection = "${ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID}=? AND ${ContactsContract.Data.MIMETYPE}=?"
            val phoneArgs = arrayOf(
                entity.phoneContactId.toNotNullable().toString(),
                ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE
            )

            val phoneUpdateOperationProvider = ContentProviderOperation.newUpdate(ContactsContract.Data.CONTENT_URI)
                .withSelection(phonesSelection, phoneArgs)
                .withValue(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER, entity.phones)
                .build()

            try {
                contentResolver.applyBatch(
                    ContactsContract.AUTHORITY,
                    arrayListOf(
                        nameUpdateOperationProvider,
                        phoneUpdateOperationProvider
                    )
                )
            } catch (ex: Exception) {}
```

Is this way of saving the contacts list correct, or there is another way of doing it?

Answer (score 0):

`Phone.NUMBER` accepts a single String, you can't set it to be a list of phone numbers, instead you need a separate `Data` entry for each phone.

Also, you're assuming the contact you're modifying already has a Phone number that you can modify, that doesn't have to be the case, I assume if entity.phones.size is different then the current number of phones stored for the contact, you want to delete/insert as necessary.

Also, running an update on selection `Phone.CONTACT_ID}=?` will update ALL phones to the same value, that's not what you want to do.

If you want to complete replace the existing set of phones to the new one, I'd recommend deleting all existing phones, and then adding all new phones.

Another issue is that all data of a contact is stored on a specific RawContact, that is a part of the contact that was synced by some service app, for example a single contact can have 2 RawContacts, one synced from Google and the other from Yahoo.
You need to decide on which RawContact you want to store your list of phones, it can be on some existing RawContact that is already a part of that contact, or a new one you create for your app.

```
val rawContact = // find the RawContact in which you want to insert your phones!!

val ops = arrayListOf(nameUpdateOperationProvider)

val phonesSelection = "${ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID}=?"
val phoneArgs = arrayOf(entity.phoneContactId.toNotNullable().toString())

// note we're running on Phone.CONTENT_URI, so no need to limit MIMTETYPE
val phonesDelete = ContentProviderOperation.newDelete(ContactsContract.Phone.CONTENT_URI) 
    .withSelection(phonesSelection, phoneArgs)
    .build()
ops.add(phonesDelete)

entity.phones.forEach {
    val addPhone = ContentProviderOperation.newInsert(ContactsContract.Phone.CONTENT_URI)
    .withValue(Phone.RAW_CONTACT_ID, rawContact)
    .withValue(Phone.NUMBER, it)
    .build()
    ops.add(addPhone)
}

try {
    contentResolver.applyBatch(ContactsContract.AUTHORITY, ops)
} catch (ex: Exception) {}
```